# SP2013 breadcrumbs work but do not display an image

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have enabled Breadcrumps in Sharepoint 2013 and they are working when I click where it should be. The problem is that there is not an image. Can anyone tell me where this image is located or why it would not show up?

My edited code is as follows,

```
    <div class="ms-breadcrumb-box ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">
                <div
                    class="ms-breadcrumb-top">
<div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox">
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaBreadcrumbDropdown" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:PopoutMenu
        Visible="true"
        runat="server"
        ID="GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout"
        IconUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"
        IconAlt="<%$Resources:wss,master_breadcrumbIconAlt%>"
        ThemeKey="v15breadcrumb"
        IconOffsetX="215"
        IconOffsetY="120"
        IconWidth="16"
        IconHeight="16"
        AnchorCss="ms-breadcrumb-anchor"
        AnchorOpenCss="ms-breadcrumb-anchor-open"
        MenuCss="ms-breadcrumb-menu ms-noList">
        <div class="ms-breadcrumb-top">
            <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="ms-breadcrumb-header" Text="<%$Resources:wss,master_breadcrumbHeader%>" />
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:ListSiteMapPath
                runat="server"
                SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPContentMapProvider"
                RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
                PathSeparator=""
                CssClass="ms-breadcrumb"
                NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-breadcrumbNode"
                CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-breadcrumbCurrentNode"
                RootNodeStyle-CssClass="ms-breadcrumbRootNode"
                NodeImageOffsetX="217"
                NodeImageOffsetY="210"
                NodeImageWidth="16"
                NodeImageHeight="16"
                NodeImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"
                RTLNodeImageOffsetX="199"
                RTLNodeImageOffsetY="210"
                RTLNodeImageWidth="16"
                RTLNodeImageHeight="16"
                RTLNodeImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"
                HideInteriorRootNodes="true"
                SkipLinkText="" />
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </SharePoint:PopoutMenu>
</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?

Comment: The company I work for decided they did not want them in the final release. I stopped trouble shooting this issue. The issue was able to be fixed if you inject/use your own images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue as well, and here is how I solved it.

**Symptoms**

- I'd removed the "*style='display:none'*" attribtue on the breadcrumb div;
- and I'd set the "*Visible*" attribute of the asp control back to "*true*".
- Despite the drop down is showing, the icon was blank.

**Resolution**

1. Open F12 developer tool in IE, locate in the HTML *"ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox"* class.
2. Follow the HTML DOM into the div and you'll eventually find a hyperlink <a> that contains the ID *"GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout-anchor"*.
3. Within this link you'll find an <img> tag, check the URL in the "*src*" attribute, attempt to load this image directly in a web browser.
4. Chances are the file specified in that <img> tag does not exist (i.e. it'd return a 404). This could be because your master page was of a custom theme to begin with, or some other bizarre SharePoint problem.
5. Open SharePoint designer, navigate where that image should be, and try to locate that image file, if it doesn't exist, copy the default one that's located in "/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23" and rename it to the one that's supposed to be there.
6. Refresh the cache on your internet browser and the image should load correctly this time.

As usual, it may not the resolution for everyone, nothing ever is, but hope this might come across helpful for others ;)

Comment: That sir is perfect and exactly what I was after!

Answer (score 1):

By default SharePoint 2013 doesn’t have a breadcrumb (like the 2010 version used to have). This was a very helpful feature to navigate back in your site and some users really miss it.

The good news is Microsoft didn’t remove it from SharePoint 2013, it’s just hidden in the Seattle master page.

To get it back working, you can follow these steps from this URL
http://academy.bindtuning.com/lets-bring-the-breadcrumb-back-to-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Thanks for that link, I have done that and they work but the little icon does not display for some reason. I am starting to think the issue is because I moved the navbar under the page title.

Comment: I have updated my post to include the code snippet, can you please reassess your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an answer to an old question.

Try `spcommon` as ThemeKey instead of `v15breadcrumb`. That worked for me.